# Running a js file geo targeted

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to run a js file. Currently i am using this code

```
addScript("http://domain.com/file.js");
```

but i want some code like which do execute this js file country wise some thing like this

http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js

var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country == "GB" )

Answer (score 1):

You want to serve up a .js, generated by PHP, whose content is dependent on the country from which the request comes?

If so, you can use the GeoIP extension for PHP: http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jack's answer (+1), here's some code that should work if you use the GeoIP PHP module:

```
addScript("http://domain.com/javascriptgenerator.php");
```

Then in `javascriptgenerator.php`, you simply do:

```
<?php 
header("Content-type: application/javascript"); //Tell the browser we're sending JS

require_once "Net/GeoIP.php"; //Path to GeoIP PHP module

$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance("/path/to/geoipdb.dat");

try {
   switch ($geoip->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) { 
        case "CA":
           //Generate JS for Canadian users
        break;
        case "FR":
           //Generate JS for French users
        break;
        //Any number of case statements goes here
        default:
           //Show default JS code 
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
   //Handle exception
   //You probably want to show the default JS code if the geo-location is unsuccesful
}
?>
```

See also http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-geoip.lookupcountrycode.php

Comment: is there any easy code? i want to use this `http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js

var country= geoip_country_code();`

Comment: Er...why have you added a PHP tag to this question if you don't want to use PHP at all? You can certainly use JSONP to fetch the data from `geoip.js` on the client-side, but then you'll be sending over *all* JS code for every single country in the world, and picking which one you want to use on the client side only. Depending on how different these JS files you want to be serving are, this could lead to a huge waste of bandwidth and make your page a lot slower than it needs to be. So if this PHP code is not what you are looking for, you need to make your question clearer :)